# Keeping track of the ID of a selected div element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, race-condition

I have a web app that uses items (div elements) organized in a column, and have a problem keeping track of which item is currently selected by user.

I currently do it by keeping an internal variable (e.g. `item_id`) that holds the ID of a selected item. Deleting a currently selected item will select an item that is directly below the deleted item. When an item is deleted on client side, it sends an AJAX call to server. This call sends the ID of the item to delete. If the call finishes successfully, then `item_id` is updated. I am using asynchrous AJAX calls. When user repeatedly (and very quickly!) deletes items, `item_id` sometimes goes out of sync. I want to prevent this behaviour.

Here is what I think how this problem occurs. Let's say I have a list of 3 items `['apple','banana','coconut']` and `'apple'` is currently selected. To visualize, it would look something like this. "{}" indicates a selected item and "X" is a button for deleting items.

```
+---------+---+
| {apple} | X |
| banana  | X |
| coconut | X |
+---------+---+
```

Then, the following could happen.

1. User deletes `'apple'` and an AJAX call to delete `'apple'` is initiated.
2. User deletes `'banana'` and an AJAX call to delete `'banana'` is initiated.
3. The AJAX call from Step 2 finishes first. `item_id` now holds the ID of `'coconut'`.
4. The AJAX call from Step 1 finally finishes. 'item_id' now holds the ID of `'banana'`.

At this point, the only item left in the list is `'coconut'`, but `item_id` holds the ID of `'banana'` which no longer exists. This is a problem for me.

Since these calls are asynchronous, there is a race between them. I used a plug-in to serialize AJAX calls that use a queue, but it seems that there is still a race condition on which call gets into the queue first.

How should I implement this so that `item_id` never goes out of sync and correctly points to a selected item in the list?

**EDIT: Here is the simplified code I use to delete an item.**

```
function deleteItem (item_id) {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/update.php',
            data : {
            item_id : item_id
        }
    })
    .done(function () {
        var deleted_item = $('#' + item_id);
        var nearest_list = deleted_item.next();

        // use the item below if it exists, otherwise get it from above
        nearest_item = nearest_item.length !== 0 ? nearest_item : deleted_item.prev();

        deleted_item.remove();

        if (nearest_item.length === 0) { // i.e. there are no more items in the list
            doSomething();
        } else if (item_id === selected_item_id) { // you deleted a selected item
            var nearest_item_id = nearest_item.attr('id');

            $('#' + nearest_item_id).addClass('selected-item');

            selected_item_id = nearest_item_id;

            loadItem(nearest_item_id);
        }
    })
    .fail(function (err,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        handleError(err,errorThrown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. There are several possibilities to work around this problem, such as having each Ajax call keep track of which ID it belongs to (using closures), or preventing simultaneous requests, but I don't want to write the whole thing from scratch for you when you probably just need a few minor tweaks to your existing code.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, I added my code. I used a plugin from http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/ to prevent simultaneous requsts, but it seems that there is still a race on which request gets into the queue. `item_id` still went out of sync in some situations.

Comment: For each invocation of the `deleteItem()` function, its `item_id` parameter will continue to hold the id even while the async Ajax is taking place, so within the `.done()` handler `item_id` _will_ still be the right id for the Ajax request just completed regardless of how many requests take place at once. Why are you using `.slice(1)` on an item's id?

Comment: That is correct and this is exactly why I have this problem. Once a request finishes and reaches the `.done()`, it does not know whether the item below has been deleted by another Ajax request. `.slice(1)` is irrelevant. I just forgot to simply my code. I'll update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is called overflow. The user clicks faster than you can communicate deletions to the server, "more than one element" doesn't fit in a container that can only hold one element, and consequently the behaviour becomes undefined (and undesirable).

The solution: don't use a single variable to track deletions, use a list.

1. user hits delete -> push this element to the `deletion` queue, disable element on the page so it can't be clicked anymore (looks grayed out, etc).
2. ajax call to delete to the server -> pop element from the `deletion` queue and add it to a `pending` qeueu
3. sever says "I deleted it" -> pop the element from the `pending` queue and remove it from the page.

So your idea was good, and the only problem was that you accidentally used a single `var` when you actually needed a stack/queue/array/list/whathaveyou.

Comment: I also thought about disabling items during deletion. But if items are disabled once user hits delete, this means only one element can be in a queue. Why would I need a queue here? Maybe I missed something.

Comment: no, you disable the item so that it no longer listens to clicks (so that it can't be added to the queue a second/third/etc time).

Comment: I get it now. I already have the `deleition` queue from using this [plugin](http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue). I am gonig to create a queue for callbacks (`pending`) and process each in order. This is probably going to work.